# How to create Botton that run clickevent on Another Botton in java?

Tags: java

I have this code

```
public class NewClass {
private void btn_NumberONEMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
}   
private void btn_NumberTOWMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
}
```

I have 2 Bottons ( Btn number One & Btn Number Tow )

I Want The First Botton will do click Event on the secound Botton

How can I do it ??

Comment: Do not forget to validate my answer if it helped you Abdullah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `doClick()` method of the `JButton` class

Here is the code :

```
    JButton but = new JButton();
    JButton but2 = new JButton();

    but.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            but2.doClick();
        }
    });

    but2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("It works !");
        }
    });
```

I did not use your variables because I didn't understand your methods.

But this works perfectly.